# Facebook Request for Permission cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: facebook

I have a web app that allows users to tie their Facebook account to our site's login and use them interchangeably.

In Internet Explorer 8 & 9 FB logged in users receive an error when trying to connect their FB account with ours.
[image: FB cannot display in frame error]

When I click on the link in the error message, I get the following page:
[image: FB endpoint deprecated]

I am using a very old API version v0.4 at
http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php

The javascript code is:

```
FB_RequireFeatures(["Api"], function()
    {
        FB.init("<?php echo HSWI_FB_KEY ?>", "/xd_receiver.htm");
        var api = FB.Facebook.apiClient;
        var permissions = 'email,publish_stream';
        FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog(permissions, function(response)
        {
            if(response.indexOf("publish_stream") === -1)
            {
                // user denied the publish_stream extended permission
                $("input.fb_publish_stream").each(
                    function(i)
                    {
                        this.checked = false;
                    }
                );
            }

            api.users_hasAppPermission('email', function(response2)
            {
                if(response.indexOf("email") === -1 && response2 !== 1)
                {
                    // user denied the email extended permission
                    // showAskForEmail();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#facebookRegForm').submit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This used to work and nothing on the page has changed on my end.

I am new to FB integration, this is a project that I have inherited.

Is there a known workaround for this?

Am I going to have to update my API version?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Facebook made a lot of changes to their authentication, and so I highly recommend that you move to the current api. Regardless, I'm not aware of any workaround for your problem.

Comment: as @NitzanTomer suggests, you might have to move to the latest sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my FB SDK code to the most recent versions of the JS (async) & PHP SDK (v.3.1.1).

This fixed my problem.